# Plugin not properly prepared for localization

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation, localization

I published my first plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-google-analytics/) on WordPress.org and I get this notice about it not being prepared for localization, even though it's perfectly translated when I use it in the admin.

I've read through the [how to internationalize your plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/) guide and I can't put my finger on anything missing from the plugin.

My plugin is structured as follows:

```
plugin-folder/
── lang/
│   ├── ahr.pot
│   ├── ahr-da_DK.po
│   ├── ahr-da_DK.mo
├── plugin-file.php
```

I have the follow WP Plugin meta in the plugin file:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Multiple Google Analytics
Plugin URI: {uri...}
Description: {desc...}
Version: 1.0.0
Text Domain: ahr
Domain Path: /lang
License: GPL v3
*/
```

I'm loading the textdomain like this:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {
  load_plugin_textdomain( 'ahr', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang/' );
});
```

Any idea what might be missing? Again, the plugin IS actually translated and the strings update when I change the locale in the admin. It's just on WordPress.org that I get the notice it isn't localization ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the [text domain has to match the plugin slug](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/#text-domains) on wordpress.org. After changing the plugin text domain to `multi-google-analytics` the notice went away.

Comment: Great you found it. For future reference it would be nice if you provided a link to the requirement and maybe a little more explanation. Also, please accept your own answer, so the system registers this question as solved.

Comment: Of course. Added a link to the docs mentioning the requirement. I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer.